# Viewpager not wrapping content after loading images from internet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager that holds images loaded by Nostra's Universal Image Loader. This viewpager is also part of a listview as a header. Setting the height to wrap_content doesn't work and it shows nothing but if I set it to a specific dip, it works. My suspect is that, the viewpager gets to wrap its content before loading the images so it doesn't show anything.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@id/viewpager"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <com.sblive.other.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Part of the PagerAdapter for the ViewPager:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_item, container,false);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    display(img, list.get(position), progressBar);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Views don't recalculate height (or width) when `"wrap_content"` is used. So it won't refresh itself when items are added dynamically. You may call it Android's limitation.

You can recalculate it's height and set it to the largest child by overriding onMeasure method of your viewPager.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int height = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(h > height) height = h;
    }

    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

You can set it equal to the height of viewpager's first child too.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    View child = getChildAt(0);
    child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();

    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you can make use of layout_weight properly as well to make the viewpager occupy remaining space in parent.